# find one or more element in strings array in another strings array

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
first_array = ['aaa', 'eee']
second_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
```

In Python, I want to determine whether any of the elements from the first array (one or more) are present in the second array.

I attempted using subset and union, but it wasn't very effective. I dont want to use the loop as it takes time

Comment: Those lists are tiny, why does it have to be "effective"?

Comment: Are the lists always sorted, as in your example?

Comment: its a big and its not sorted

Comment: Would be good if you could share a little code that generates realistic data so we could properly benchmark the various approaches.

Comment: Could also help to know *how* big each list is, how likely a value is in both, and whether this is a one-time thing or you do this multiple times with for example one of the lists always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if set(first_array) & set(second_array):
    print("There are some shared elements")
```

Since this takes time to construct two sets, it will be slower than the naive array implementation on short arrays, but much more performant on large ones.

Answer (score 0):

first_array = ['aaa', 'eee']
second_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']

```
for x in first_array:
    if x in second_array:
        print(f"{x} is in second_array")
```

Without an loop this would it be:

```
set(first_array).intersection(set(second_array))
```

This will Output if and what is in both lists

I Hope this Helps :)

Comment: i really dont want to loop them it s not effective

Comment: I updated it now it has no loop

Answer (score 0):

This turns only the smaller list into a set and stops looking at the other list's elements early if it finds a shared value. And it does all the hard work in C, not Python.

```
small, large = sorted((first_array, second_array), key=len)
result = not set(small).isdisjoint(large)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
result = any([x in second_array for x in first_array])
```